# Unable to get react to work in requirejs environment

Tags: reactjs, requirejs

I have a regular ol' requirejs app, that pulls in modules in regular JS I write. I really want to start using reactjs but am not even able to get it to load with out throwing errors in the console. 
My Paths

```
'react': '../node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min', // there is a cjs and a umd (Universal Module Definition) version, I dont think I am UMD. we are Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD)
        'reactDOM': '../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min',
        'JSXTransformer': 'vendors/react/JSXTransformer-0.10.0',
        'jsx': 'vendors/react/jsx',
```

Is it possible that there is a shim dependency that I need to setup?

```
'react' : {
        'deps' : ['jquery']
       },
       'reactDOM' : {
        'deps' : ['jquery']
       }
```

I have also included them normally such as

```
require(["jquery", "jqueryUi", "bootstrap", "react", "reactDOM", "front", "owlCarousel", "select2", "blockui", ], function ($, jqueryUi, bootstrap, React, ReactDOM, front, owlCarousel, select2, blockui) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    require([ $('#requirePageSpecificJs').val() ]); // this is set in php, result: "/require-mturk.js" 
  });
});
```

I get this error, when loading a page.

[image]

I am completely new to React, so I may be missing some things. Does the latest react require Babel to run, and if so do I need to include babel as a package, and add that as a shim? I am seeing some other posts of using requirejs with react but it is requiring different tools and stuff. completely lost here.

Comment: I don't know enough about amd to give you a specific answer, but you don't need babel if you're not using jsx. is there any benefit to adding react to your amd pipeline? maybe just load it from a cdn

Comment: I'm using require js with react and grunt. If you tell me at where your getting an error like importing react components or anything . Any explanations would be helpful